# How to prevent one file from .htaccess redirect?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am creating php front controller. this is my `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    (.*) controller.php    [L]
</IfModule>
```

This code redirect all url to the `controller.php`. I need to avoid redirect `index.php` to the `controller.php`. All other urls should redirect to the `controller.php`.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210931/htaccess-redirect-all-but-one-page-from-html-to-php

Comment: you are welcome. keep upvoting and supporting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to make an exception:

```
RewriteRule name_of_page_to_exclude.php - [L]
```

The dash (`-`) is important. The `[L]` makes sure that if this rule is triggered, it's the last one that will be processed. So naturally, you'll need to place it near the top of your `.htaccess` file, before the rule in your question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule name_of_page_to_exclude.php - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) controller.php [L]
```

The [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) has the following to say:

> - (dash)
>   A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following condition :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This shall allow any files that actually exist and assumes it wouldn't mess up anything else for other files that already exist.